# How to keep the MATHJAX formatting applied to the website content?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, mathjax

I have following HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="somediv1">
    Some LATEX TEXT
  </div>
  <div id="somediv2">
    Some LATEX TEXT
  </div>
  <button id="button1"><button>
  <button id="button2"><button>

  <script>
    $('#somediv1').show();
    $('#somediv2').hide();          


    $('#button1').click(function(){
      $('#somediv1').hide();
      $('#somediv2').show();
    });
    $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#somediv2').hide();
      $('#somediv1').show();
    });
  </script>
  <script> //this include mathjax from mathjax cdn
  </script>
</body>
```

Now, the problem:

When the page first loads, the text in `somediv1` gets formatted by `Mathjax`.
However when i click on any of the buttons the `div` elements hide and when they are shown aganin they do not get formatted, as `Mathjax` gets applied only once. How can i keep the `Mathjax` applied to the LATEX text inside these div elements.

UPDATE:
The text inside `somediv` elements is not normal LATEX text but highly formatted (Read a lots of HTML tags included). And, I wish to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer!

I used `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` at every click event.

Its working perfectly.

References:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/typeset.html